# Array reordering

Tags: iphone, arrays

I am trying to reorder an array (moving one item of 90 to the top, and move all the others down).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray* array;
...
id ninety = [array objectAtIndex:90];
[ninety retain];  // needs retain because -removeObject will release that object.
[array removeObjectAtIndex:90];
[array insertObject:ninety atIndex:0];
[ninety release];
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's a `NSMutableArray` you can use `-exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:` to swap item 0 and the one you want to move to the top.  No need to mess with `retain` and `release`.

(Edited - this is not exactly what the questioner wanted - the reponse by KennyTM is the correct one for that case)

Comment: Doesent the item 0 move to the bottom then?

Comment: I didn't read your question carefully enough - I thought you just wanted to swap.  KennyTM's response is correct in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an NSMutableArray. Remove the object you want to move with `removeObjectAtIndex:` and then stick it back in its new location with `insertObject:atIndex:`.

Answer (score -1):

1) keep in mind item 90
2) move items 0..89 one slot down (can use func memmove())
3) put former '90' item in slot 0

Comment: I'm pretty sure using memmove() with an NSArray would lead to disaster.  It's not like we are talking C arrays here.

Comment: Agreed, that is a horrible idea.